# AEM Forms - include CQ Widget to get the CQ.User object (get user name)

Tags: aem

Is it possible to get the currently logged in user name in Javascript in AEM Forms? I did a bit of research and it seems like I need to include the cq:widgets library however cannot find its relative path in AEM 6.3 / not sure how to include it in my component.

Tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/CQ.js"></script>

<cq:include script="/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/CQ.js"/>
```

I still cannot get the CQ.User object in chrome.

Comment: Try finding the relevant category for this JS and include the category in your component's code. You don't normally script include libraries from AEM as those paths are blocked in a secured environment.

Comment: Thanks, in this case the category should be cq:widgets. However adding this to the component jsp doesnt bring in the widgets library